# How does Hungering Arrow work?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I would like more detail on the mechanics of Hungering Arrow than the tooltips give me. I know that it "seeks out" enemies, and it has a chance to pierce targets (which varies depending on runes).

- How close to a target does the projectile have to be for it to "seek out" that target? Is this constant, or variable?
- Will it "seek out" targets on its way to an enemy I specifically clicked?
- Are destructible objects and/or destructible containers valid targets for "seeking out"? If so, does the projectile prefer enemies over objects? I'm wondering if I can be screwed by firing at enemies surrounded by barrels.

Comment: RE:3, I don't believe I've ever seen a Hungering Arrow seek out an object. Pretty sure they'll only hit those if specifically targeted.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I thought I had, but I guess I wouldn't put money on it.

Comment: Blizzard really does need to update tooltips, Smoke Screen also does a lot more than described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience as Demon Hunter with Hungering Arrow tells me this:

- The target can be just off screen, it has quite a distance it can
  travel. Mind that the arrow then will target the closest creature off screen, it's quite *random*.
- you cannot click on the monster itself, it will try and
  find one for you.  As long as you don't shoot in the opposite
  direction of the required target. (General direction will do.)
- Hungering Arrow does seek out destructible items if you click on it
  as a target. If there is a monster nearby and you *haven't* selected
  a destructible as target, it will shoot that monster.
- It can pierce the target multiple times, and fly back to strike it again.

Either way, if a monster so foolishly stands in between the barrel and you, it will get hit. Hungering Arrow goes into a straight line and does not dodge other targets in order to reach its final target.

For **115%** weapon damage, and a **35%** chance to pierce, it's a great skill even in Inferno. With Devouring Arrow as rune (70% damage per consecutive pierce) it is formidable.

Comment: It can also loop back and pierce the same target multiple times.